# How create a simple maven project in eclipse for develop portlet liferay 6.2 with primefaces (on jboss)

Tags: eclipse, maven, primefaces, jboss, portlet

I want to create a portlet with primefaces by a maven project in eclipse.
I've installed liferay 6.2 on existing installation on jboss as 7.1.1.
I'm follow last part of this guide http://www.hascode.com/2011/07/creating-portlets-with-java-server-faces-2-and-liferay but don't work. It give me java ClassNotFoundException org.portletfaces.bridge.GenericFacesPortlet.
I'm trying this: https://www.liferay.com/it/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/developing-plugins-using-maven-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-02-en but my screen of liferay ide in eclipse is different of this: https://www.liferay.com/c/document_library/get_file?groupId=14&uuid=fee78cb9-59fd-4547-baa1-58bc7e1eebf9 (I have not build type).
Help me please.
Thank you!

Comment: A good tutorial on seting up primefaces using eclipse and maven http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INkvO9qzLnk&hd=1

Comment: thank you makky, but I want to know how to configure maven project to do a liferay portlet with primefaces

Answer (score 0):

*org.portletfaces.bridge.GenericFacesPortlet* is contained within the Maven dependency *org.portletfaces:portletfaces-bridge:2.0.0*. How have you built the project?

Also I'm not able to open the screenshot you've posted (The requested resource was not found.).